# The rand() function in C++ is giving a number outside the range

Tags: c++, random

So I'm trying to write a story about Jordan paying bills and stuff. I used a rand function to find a random number for his salary 3.5k - 4.5 and bills 700 -1.5k. I believe I got the formula right but usually, it generates a number outside that area. Below is the code and result.

```
{
    srand(time(NULL));  
    cout << fixed;
    cout << setprecision(2);
    float money = 9000;
    int minbill = 700;
    int maxbill = 1500;
    int minsal = 3500;
    int maxsal = 4500;
    float rent = 3000;

    cout << "[Jordan's Balance: Gp" << money << "]\n\n";
    cout << "Jordan's rent costs Gp" << rent <<".\n";
    float bill = (rand()%maxbill-minbill+1)+minbill;
    cout << "Jordan's bills costs Gp" << bill << ".\n";
    float totalb = rent + bill;
    cout << "Jordan needs to pay a total of Gp" << totalb << "\n\n";
    float sal = (rand()%maxsal-minsal+1)+minsal;
    cout << "Jordan received a salary of Gp" << sal << "!!\n";
    money = money + sal;
    cout << "[Jordan's Balance: Gp" << money << "]\n\n";
}
```

I expect Jordan's bills to be around 700-1.5k and his salary 3.5k-4.5k but it gives me a number below that.

```
Jordan's rent costs Gp3000.00.
Jordan's bills costs Gp133.00.
Jordan needs to pay a total of Gp3133.00

Jordan received a salary of Gp1906.00!!
[Jordan's Balance: Gp10906.00]
```

Comment: You're close.  Try this: `minbill + ( std::rand() % ( maxbill - minbill + 1 ) )`.  And definitely parenthesize!

Comment: You do not use enough brackets, so check Operator Precedence https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Don't `std::rand`.  It is officially known as the "low quality random number generator."  Use `<random>` instead.  (`std::default_random_engine`, `std::uniform_int_distribution`)

Comment: @L.F. -- I looked for your quotation in the C11 and the C++17 standards and I can't find it. Where is this assertion "officially" made?

Comment: @PeteBecker 29.6.9 Low-quality random number generation [\[c.math.rand\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/c.math.rand)

Comment: @L.F. -- AHA! You misquoted it! <g> I searched for "low quality", but it's "low-quality". You dropped the apostrophe (cue Trumpian outrage). Note, however, that section titles are not normative. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker Oops, I am so sorry for dropping the (name of the required punctuation)!  I didn't know it can affect the search results ...

Comment: @L.F. -- I was surprised, too. The PDF reader that I use ignores whitespace, but that hyphen fooled it.

Answer (score 1):

`(rand()%maxbill-minbill+1)` is wrong.

It's possible that `rand()%maxbill` will be less than `minbill`. You need to use `rand() % (maxbill - minbill + 1)`.

```
float bill = rand() % (maxbill-minbill+1) + minbill;
```

Similarly, use

```
float sal = rand() % (maxsal-minsal+1) + minsal;
```